# Drop a pin on specific address using Google Maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Can somebody tell me is is possible to drop a pin on specific address on a map generated Google Maps v3 library? I need to send an address to script, and marker should be dropped on that address...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have an address, you will need to geocode it first, then you can create the marker:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addressThatYouWannaDraw }, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      pt = results[0].geometry.location;

      var myMarkerOpts = {
        position: pt,
        map: map
      };

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(myMarkerOpts);
    }
  });
```

map here is your **google.map.Map** element